# Compare files string by string

Tags: java, string, file, methods

I have two files:

```
Grader.getFileInfo("data\\studentSubmissionA.txt");
Grader.teacherFiles("data\\TeacherListA.txt");
```

Both contain a list of math problems, but the TeacherList is unsolved in order to check that the StudentSubmission was not altered from the original version.

studentSubmission is sent to the Grader class and the method currently looks like this:

```
public static void getFileInfo(String fileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName))

    while (in.hasNext()) { 
    String fileContent = in.nextLine();
     }
```

and the TeacherFiles method looks like

```
    public static void teacherFiles(String teacherFiles) 
        throws FileNotFoundException{

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(teacherFiles));

    while (in.hasNext()){
        String teacherContent = in.nextLine();

        String line = teacherContent.substring(0, teacherContent.indexOf('='));
    }
```

I don't know how to get these methods to another method in order to compare them since they're coming from a file and I have to put something in the method signature to pass them and it doesn't work.

I tried putting them in one method, but that was a bust as well.

I don't know where to go from here.

And unfortunately, I can't use try/catches or arrays.

Is it possible to send the .substring(0 , .indexof('=')) through the methods?

Like `line = teacherFiles(teacherContent.substring(0 , .indexof('=')));` Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It is labwork, and I can't use arrays. If I could, this would be a million times simpler and I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Declare `String line = "";` in the `main` method. Then you can just do `line = teacherFiles(teacherContent.substring(0 , .indexof('=')));` in your method instead of `String line = teacherFiles(teacherContent.substring(0 , .indexof('=')));`. Then you can use line in other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Think in more general terms. Observe that your methods called `getFileInfo` and `teacherFiles`, respectively are the very same except a few nuances. So why do not we think about finding the optimal way of merging the two functionalities and handling the nuances outside of them?

It is logical that you cannot use arrays as you need to know the number of elements of your array before you initialize it and your array would have already been initialized when you read the file.  So using an array for this task is either an overkill (for example you allocate 1000 elements in your memory and you use only 10 elements) or insufficient (if you create an array of 10 elements, but you would need 1000). So, due to the fact that you do not know the number of rows in advance you need to use another data structure for your task.

So create the following method:

```
public static AbstractList<String> readFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
    AbstractList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (s.hasNext()){
        list.add(s.next());
    }
    s.close();
    return list;

}
```

Then use the method to read the student file and to read the teacher file. Store the results into two separate `AbstractList<String>` variables, then iterate through them and compare them as you like. Again, think in more general terms.